# Meteor - Inserting Settings Array into Profile of User is not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using the default User Accounts Meteor package and trying to implement basic settings for each user. Since the User Accounts package comes with a profile field I figured this would be the perfect place to insert an array to hold settings of that particular user.

Here is the code I used.

```
 var profile  = 
 {
 settings:
   [{
     id_: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(),
     rule_id: "name1",
     turned_on: false,
     date_created: new Date(),
     date_updated:new Date()
   },
   {
     id_: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(),
     rule_id: "name2",
     turned_on: false,
     date_created: new Date(),
     date_updated:new Date()
   }
  ]};
Accounts.createUser({username: email, email: email, password: password, profile: profile }, //callback etc etc..
```

I get no error on the call of Accounts.createUser but when I print the user in console -->  the profile field is empty : "profile" : {  }

P.S. insecure and autopublish are installed right now.

I think I am over-looking something very easy here. Any help is appreciated!
Thank you :)
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Asked this question a little prematurely :/ Was able to figure out! :)

Although I still wasn't able to insert profile information via the Accounts.createUser() method, here's the way I solved it.

1.call Accounts.createUser(etc etc)

2.inside callback function, get current user id with Meteor.userId(); i.e. var userId = Meteor.userId();

3.call Meteor.users.update({_id:userId}, {$set:{profile:profile}}) //using profile array mentioned in original question.

I sincerely hopes this helps someone out in the future!
Alex

Comment: If the settings are something you don't want the user to be able to edit, then they should not go in the profile property.

Comment: @SirCharlesWatson These will all be edited by the user :) that's why I chose the profile field.

Comment: Ok! Just making sure! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Accounts.onCreateUser` to modify the user's profile. That's a pretty standard pattern.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  user.profile = {
    settings:
     [{
       id_: Random.id(),
       rule_id: "name1",
       turned_on: false,
       date_created: new Date(),
       date_updated: new Date()
     },
     {
       id_: Random.id(),
       rule_id: "name2",
       turned_on: false,
       date_created: new Date(),
       date_updated: new Date()
     }
    ]};
  return user;
});
```

Here using `Random.id()` instead of `new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()`

Comment: where and how is the options object declared?

Comment: It's a parameter that is passed to [Accounts.createUser()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) so you would define it yourself in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code seems to work in [this Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/KpmL9ezimjPCqtiDX/Leaderboard). What were you doing that was different?

Things to check:

1. accounts-password package installed?
2. username/email is unique?
3. `Accounts.createUser()` callback is not being passed an error?